# ¿Cual es el uso correcto de ExecuteScalar en C#?

Tags: c#, poo, funciones, variables, vb

En VB.net tengo un objeto que realiza consultas de resultado único. Es este: (Resultado es una variable de tipo String).

```
Sub ConsultarSQL(Instruccion)        
    Resultado = vbEmpty
    ConectarSQL()
    Conexion.Open()
    Try
        Comando = New SqlCommand(Instruccion, Conexion)
        Resultado = Comando.ExecuteScalar()
        Conexion.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Resultado = vbEmpty
        Conexion.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Y puedes realizar cualquier consulta, y no importa el tipo de dato que regrese. Intento migrar mis funciones a C# pero no logro que este funcione igual. He hecho esto:

```
 public int ConsultarSQL(string sql)
    {
        Conexion.Open();
        try
        {
            comando = new SqlCommand(sql, Conexion);
            return (int)comando.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        finally
        {
            Conexion.Close();
        }
    }
```

Y solo he logrado que funcione con enteros, pero si el resultado fuera una fecha o una cadena no funciona. Me dice que no puedo convertir a Cadena. si reemplazo por ejemplo int por string me dice que no puedo realizar conversión a string. ¿como puedo hacer esa función genérica como en vb.net?

Comment: Una recomendacion, no programes de esa forma creando metodos auto-magicos porque vas a tener miles de problemas

Comment: Muy amable tu sugerencia. La razón es por que son funciones muy repetitivas y esto evita escribir lo mismo miles de veces. Es una forma de simplificar el programa y hasta el momento no habia tenido ningun problema. Hasta aqui migrando a C#, entiendo que vb.net simplifica muchisimo las cosas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si lo que esperas es un string entonces usa:

```
comando.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Ten en cuenta que entonces tu función tendría que devolver string en lugar de int. Si lo que pretendes es hacer una función genérica, entonces que devuelva object pero debemos saber el tipo de dato esperado.

```
public object ConsultarSQL(string sql, Type tipoDatoEsperado)
{
    Conexion.Open();
    try
    {
        comando = new SqlCommand(sql, Conexion);
        if (tipoDatoEsperado == typeof(int))
           return (int)comando.ExecuteScalar();
        if (tipoDatoEsperado == typeof(string))
           return comando.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        Conexion.Close();
    }
}
```

Una llamada que espera una string como resultado sería así:

```
string MiResultado = (string)ConsultarSQL(miConsulta, typeof(string));
```

Comment: Entiendo que aquí en tu ejemplo se especifica de antemano el tipo de dato que se espera recibir.

Comment: Correcto, se entiende que cuando haces una consulta esperas un tipo de dato concreto. Si tu consulta va de la sumatoria de artículos vendidos, esperas un tipo int. Si tu consulta va sobre la persona que más venta ha realizado y esperas un nombre pues será de tipo string.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres definir en c# una funcionalidad en donde el tipo de dato pueda varias debes usar `generics`

[c# generics](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

```
public T ConsultarSQL<T>(string sql)
{
    Conexion.Open();
    try
    {
        var comando = new SqlCommand(sql, Conexion);
        return (T)comando.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    finally
    {
        Conexion.Close();
    }
}
```

Para usarlo seria

```
string query = "SELECT ...";

string result = ConsultarSQL<string>(query );
```

[Default(T) In Generics](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/defaultt-in-generics/)

Comment: Interesante, me parece que esto es lo que mas se aproxima a lo que esperaba lograr, voy a estudiar la bibliografía que añadiste de Generics. Independientemente de eso, veo que usas aqui var que es una variable que especifica el tipo de forma implicita. Lo cual es muy util.